# Irregular Verbs in first and third person plural

Tags: conjugation, irregular-verb

For a regular German verb, the infinitive, first person plural and third person plural are the same - e.g. *fahren; wir fahren; sie fahren*.

For almost all of the common irregular verbs I've seen, this also seems to be the case - e.g. *haben; wir haben; sie haben*.

*Sein* is an exception, but even here the first and third person plural forms are the same - *sein; wir sind; sie sind*.

- Are there any other irregular verbs in which the infinitive and first/third plural forms differ?
- Are there **any** verbs in which the first and third person plural forms differ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To put it simple, the infinitive, first and third person plural present tense are the same for all verbs but *sein*. The first and third person plural are identical in their respective tense/mood for all verbs.

There aren't too many really irregular verbs in German either. The most of those you see as irregular are **strong verbs**, which also follow one of seven patterns (which you should not learn, by the way.)

Answer (score 9):

Well, for verbs with separable particles the infinitive will differ, regardless of the irregularity. 
E.g. *einladen* - *wir laden ein*, *sie laden ein*. But that is somewhat nitpicky as they generally can be simplified to the word without particle (*laden*), even if that word might be archaic by now.

A similar case exists for reflexive verbs. ***sich*** *erinnern* - *wir erinnern* ***uns***, *sie erinnern* ***sich***. Again, the second part changes, but it feels like cheating..

Otherwise, I cannot think about an example apart from *sein*.